# Need help with level shifting and amplifying a signal

Tags: amplifier, level-shifting

I have a 1V pk to pk analogue signal and need to shift and amplify the voltage to 0.5-2V.The supply into the amplifier is ±10V. The frequency of the signal is 500 - 1000Hz.

What sort of circuit should I be looking at? Not wanting anyone to send circuits, just need some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Opamps for everyone. Noninverting amplifier

Comment: Might be easier to do the bias with an inverting amp except it will invert

Comment: Are you able to use +/- power supplies, or are you limited to + power.

Comment: what source impdance? is source DC_blocked?

Comment: How precise do you want the 0.5 V and 2 V to be? How accurate is your 1 V pk-pk signal and what's it centred around (e.g. is it +/- 0.5 V)?   (Please edit info' into your question, don't put info' in comments)

Comment: Digital or analog signal? What frequencies it has?

Comment: post has been edited**

Comment: Welcome. A hard but essential thing to learn in engineering is how to define things specifically and clearly enough when you're already very familiar with something. Then it can be understood by people totally unfamiliar with it, such as us. I imagine you're hoping to ask a short question you don't have to spend much time on but still get the clear answer you want. From our point of view, it's much too vague and we can only give vague one-line answers. For that reason, I'll have to vote to close. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.